# Join two tables with multiple rows and apply where

Tags: php, mysql

Table colors:

```
id - color
1 - red
2 - blue
3 - black
```

Table marks:

```
color_id - mark
1 - fan
2 - lamp
1 - car
2 - switch
2 - house
```

Query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM colors c 
LEFT JOIN marks m ON m.color_id = c.id 
WHERE m.mark = 'fan' OR m.mark = 'switch'
GROUP BY c.id
```

This is expected to return the rows with red and blue, but that does not happen, why is that?

Comment: Only returns row with red.

Comment: As an aside your `left join` is really an `inner join` because you put a where clause on the fields on the RIGHT side

Comment: what is the group by in there for? without that, i would expect you to get two records back linked to fan and switch

Comment: This should work fine. You can use an `inner join`, though. Theoretically it will perform better, and the result will be the same, because of the conditions in the where clause. -edit- what @ConradFrix said. :p

Comment: This should work fine, unless there is some typo in the data or in the query. Maybe there's a space after `switch` in the database, or something silly like that.

Comment: SELECT c.* FROM marks m 
INNER JOIN colors c ON m.color_id = c.id 
WHERE m.mark = 'fan' OR m.mark = 'switch'
GROUP BY c.id

Comment: Changing it to inner join does nothing. Here is the real query i use: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS m.*, t.tag FROM media m
  LEFT JOIN sets s ON m.`set` = s.id
  LEFT JOIN tags_assigned ta ON m.id = ta.file_id
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = ta.tag_id
  WHERE (s.name LIKE '%car%' OR s.description LIKE '%car%' OR m.description LIKE '%car%' OR t.tag = 'car')

Comment: Got it. There was a white space character in the marks table behind few of the marks. Thats 3 hours of my life i will never see again.